# Get the distinct set of sets in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For [day 12 of Advent of Code](http://adventofcode.com/2017/leaderboard/day/12) I have a solution where I end up with this type of structure:

```
let structure = new Set([
    new Set(["1", "42"]),
    new Set(["42"]),
    new Set(["1", "42"])
]);
```

At first I had naively expected the above to become equivalent to this:

```
let expected = new Set([
    new Set(["1", "42"]),
    new Set(["42"])
]);
```

But that did not happen of course because the 1st and 3rd set in `structure` are different objects, so the outer set does not de-duplicate them.

Note that in reality I have 200 sets all containing between 1 and 10 items, so the solution must perform decently.

I'm able to use any modern bit of JS that works in bleeding edge browsers (e.g. Chrome 63+), and would very much prefer to use vanilla JavaScript if possible.

What is an efficient way to get to the `expected` result with only 2 distinct sets, given either `structure` or its inner array as a starting point?

Answer (score 1):

To identify duplicates, either use lodash's [`isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#isEqual), or implement an equivalent `isEqual()` function to compare two sets (see below).

Combine that with a [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to add distinct sets to your final result set.

```
let structure = new Set([
    new Set(["1", "42"]),
    new Set(["42"]),
    new Set(["42", "1"])
]);

function isEqual(set1, set2) {
  let s1 = Array.from(set1).sort();
  let s2 = Array.from(set2).sort();
  if (s1.length != s2.length)
     return false;

  for (let i = 0; i < s1.length; i++) 
    if (s1[i] !== s2[i])
       return false;

  return true;
}

let outerSetArray = Array.from(structure);
let deduplicated = outerSetArray.reduce((aggregator, innerSet) => {
  if (!aggregator.some(s => isEqual(s, innerSet)))
      aggregator.push(innerSet);

  return aggregator;
}, []);
```

Now `deduplicated` is an array of distinct sets which you can turn back into a `Set` if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've clarified my question in a way that doesn't invalidate your answer, but I did add that I actually am after a vanilla JS solution.

Comment: @Jeroen Got it! Updated with a vanilla solution.

Comment: In your answer btw I would change the `aggregator.filter(...).length == 0` with just `aggregator.some(...)`.

Comment: @Jeroen Cool idea! Done.

Comment: @Jeroen If any of the answers has solved your problem, go ahead and accept your favorite solution. Cheers!

Comment: Aye, I have considered that. I certainly appreciate the help, and have upvoted all helpful responses, but every answer has at least one critical flaw that would for now prevent me from using it. (The one I probably "should" accept according to SO etiquette is the one I ended up useing, which is the `JSON.stringify` one because it is what I used for Advent of Code. But I don't want that answer to float to the top as advice for others landing here, instead I'll leave it up to the community to vote their "favorite" to the top.)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit expensive but will get the job done. I am not sure how much computationally undesirable this could get.

**STRATEGY 1:**

- Create a Set with stringified arrays using `JSON.stringify`.
- Convert the Set elements back to arrays using `JSON.parse`.

**STRATEGY 2:**

- Create an object with values as "-" joined strings.
- Reconstruct the array by mapping keys and splitting with "-" delimiter.

```js
// JSON STRINGIFY - JSON PARSE STRATEGY

let structure = new Set([
    new Set(["1", "42"]),
    new Set(["42"]),
    new Set(["1", "42"])
]);

const json_stringified_set = new Set([...structure].map(a => JSON.stringify([...a])))

const json_parsed_set = new Set([...json_stringified_set].map(a => JSON.parse(a)))

console.log([...json_parsed_set]);


// REDUCE - OBJECT STRATEGY

const reduced_object = [...structure].reduce((a, b) => { a[[...b].join("-")] = ""; return a }, {})

const final_set = new Set(Object.keys(reduced_object).map(a => a.split("-")))

console.log([...final_set])
```

Comment: Ahh.. yeah... I will admit that I actually resorted to [something very similar in my AoC puzzle solution](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/advent-of-code-2017/blob/bf446a288dd3d1023e3e0f19906b6023804b456f/days/12.js#L2066). It's certainly better than nothing, but I had hoped for a cleaner, faster way of doing things...

Comment: @Jeroen Please check my updated answer. How about using the reduce strategy?

Comment: Thanks again for even adding additional options. The reduce strategy shares some ideas with [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47766600/419956) and looks a lot better to me, though the relative drawback is you have to pick a join/split string that doesn't occur in your inputs. But it'll certainly work for my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function filterUniqueSets(...sets){
   const hash = {};
   return sets.filter(set => {
     const k = [...set].join("¢");
     if(hash[k]) return false;
     return hash[k] = true;
  });
}
```

So one can do:

```
 const result = new Set(filterUniqueSets(
   new Set(1,2,3),
   new Set(1,3,4)
 ));
```

Comment: Thx! Nice terse solution, probably the one I could've used for AoC, where I know the inputs. Kinda tricky though if you have unknown input that might contain the string you `join` on.

Comment: @jeroen its either slow or it has such small drawbacks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use something like this:

```js
function same(val1, val2){
  var v1, v2, s;
  if(val1 instanceof Array && val2 instanceof Array){
    var l = val1.length;
    if(l !== val2.length){
      return false;
    }
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
      v1 = val1[i]; v2 = val2[i];
      if(typeof v1 === 'object' || typeof v2 === 'object'){
        if(!same(v1, v2)){
          return false;
        }
      }
      else if(v1 !== v2){
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  else if(typeof val1 === 'object' && typeof val2 === 'object'){
    for(var i in val1){
      v1 = val1[i]; v2 = val2[i];
      if(typeof v1 === 'object' || typeof v2 === 'object'){
        if(!same(v1, v2)){
          return false;
        }
      }
      else{
        if(!(i in val2)){
          return false;
        }
        if(v1 !== v2){
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else if(val1 !== val2){
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(same(4, 4));
console.log(same(['w', 'f', 't', 4], ['w', 't', 'f', 4]));
console.log(same(['w', 't', 'f', 4], ['w', 't', 'f', 4]));
var obj1 = {here: ['a', 'b', 3], test:4, obj:{wow:[4, 'real'], cool:'works'}};
var obj2 = {here: ['a', 'b', 3], test:4, obj:{wow:[4, 'real'], cool:'works'}};
var obj3 = {here: ['a', 'b', 3], test:4, obj:{wow:[2, 'real'], cool:'works'}};
console.log(same(obj1, obj2)); console.log(same(obj1, obj3));
```

Comment: I'm a wee bit confused, don't see anything related to `Set` objects in there?

Comment: Just a  helper function, so you can test Objects or Arrays against each other. Ran out of time for more help. Sorry.